# Why does the data object has a data.username field

Tags: jquery, node.js, socket.io, chat

I am trying to learn how to make a chat App using `socket.io` ,`ejs` ,`nodejs` ...

So I am basically studying  a code from the following repo: https://github.com/ngrt/simpleChatApp

The folder structure is like
`simpleChatApp` (the parent folder)
    -views(contains `index.ejs`)
    -public (contains `style.css` and `chat.js` )
    -app.js (the file which has the server code )

app.js has `app.use(express.static('public'))`so public works as root

Now the problem is in chat.js ( which contains the client-side backend)
below picture is a part of chat.js

[image]

```
send_message.click(function(){
        socket.emit('new_message', {message : message.val()})
    })

    //Listen on new_message
    socket.on("new_message", (data) => {
        feedback.html('');
        message.val('');
        chatroom.append("<p class='message'>" + data.username + ": " + data.message + "</p>")
    })
```

In the emit part we only sent a message field .....whereas in the socket.on part we used data.username() ...Now from what I think data is basically the object we sent in emit ....which didn't contain any username ..so how can it use it ..cause its a working repo so the code is correct ..but I can't understand why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The message received by client's `socket.on` is emitted by nodejs's emit (and not client's one as in you code). This is `node js`'s code, where username is appended:

```
socket.on('new_message', (data) => {
  //broadcast the new message
  io.sockets.emit('new_message', {message : data.message, username : socket.username});
})
```

In general in your example multiple clients are listening to the server message and server is listening to each client's emit. Username is stored by the server on each new `socket` object. Initial value on connect is 'Anonymous' and is updated on `change_username` event:

```
socket.on('change_username', (data) => {
    socket.username = data.username
})
```

First *send_mesasage* [emit](https://github.com/ngrt/simpleChatApp/blob/master/public/chat.js#L16) in `chat.js` is [received](https://github.com/ngrt/simpleChatApp/blob/master/app.js#L39) by `app.js` and is immediately [emitted](https://github.com/ngrt/simpleChatApp/blob/master/app.js#L41) to all connected clients (***including the sender***). 
Server adds a user name to this emit (which was stored in `socket` object by server).

Then, each client [receives](https://github.com/ngrt/simpleChatApp/blob/master/public/chat.js#L20) this emit (which already has a username). All connected clients then [print](https://github.com/ngrt/simpleChatApp/blob/master/public/chat.js#L23) received message and username

Comment: please see my updated answer. And check https://github.com/ngrt/simpleChatApp/blob/master/app.js#L31 and https://github.com/ngrt/simpleChatApp/blob/master/app.js#L35

Comment: Ok so is it this that ... first the send_message in chat.js creates a new_message emit ..which is ignored by the socket.on('new_message') in chat.js as its an emit from the same file ....but the app.js socket.on('new_message ') catches it and it then emits another new_message which is ignored by itself cause its from the same file but captured by the chat.js one which well explains everything

Comment: Your logic is correct except of ignoring emits.  Please see my updated answer (it was too long for comment :))

Comment: But still the emit is being ignored by the chat.js one in the starting

Comment: I mean is there something like the emits of the chat.js are somehow directed towards the app.js only ...and not towards chat.js...if so what code specifies such nature

Comment: `emit` and `on` in `chat.js` are not related. There are 2 open channels: client's `emit` -> server's `on` and server's  `emit` -> client's `on`. Which means that the emits of the chat.js are directed towards the app.js only (not to chat.js)

Comment: Just one more thing ....what piece of code made the app.js a server and the chat.js a client(sort of a beginner here so might be asking something basic)

Comment: app.js is ran by node js by invoking npm start command, which is placed in package.json: "start": "nodemon app". `app.js` uses `express` library to run an HTTP server on port '3000'. The same `express` is responsible for serving static files. index.html is rendered by `ejs` view engine (configured also in `app.js`). This makes app.js a server. chart.js is just included in index.html file, thus it belongs to the client